# LinkedIn not recognising OG tags when shared via 3rd party application

Tags: url, linkedin-api, share, share-open-graph

To start with, it is worth me noting that this process was working perfectly for 2 years. It started failing intermittently about 2 weeks ago.

We enable our clients to share a URL with a custom OG image to Linkedin via our Linkedin application.

Currently, it is presenting with no 'preview' image like so https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6811038971855020032/ (screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc2b6.png)

However, when checked using [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) it works perfectly https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fjobadder.refari.co%2Fsocial%2F8e3284ec-d6b8-4d0b-b6a8-cb2a19a56432%2F (screenshot of the same thing https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfF4S.png)

If I take the URL and paste it manually into LinkedIn it also fetches the OG image with no issues. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj3Ej.png

Worth noting that the image being fetched in this example is 438kb (so not large)

As far as we can tell this is an issue with Linkedin fetching the OG image but I am more than open to being told otherwise. Any help at all would be very much appreciated.

Comment: We have 3 different companies (with 3 different dev teams) that are experiencing the same issues.

Note that if you view the posts when not logged in at all, they preview just fine. 

They only don't preview when you are logged in.  

It is a problem with the view and the type of message.

Comment: Absolutely right Rick, my recommendation is to log tickets with Linkedin regardless. They keep trying to pass me off to this stack overflow community, but this is not an issue with us not knowing how to do this, so I just keep reopening the ticket. It is an issue on Linkedin's side without a doubt.

Comment: @RickPaul if you are experiencing the same thing. Make sure you upvote the relevant questions already in this stack overflow!

Comment: I did.  It looks like I was the only one.